# determine button click and modify values in another button aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

I have dynamically created Data Table bind to Grid View. In every row I'm adding button which i'm define in grid view. Now I want that button to call in another button click event and make modifications in values.Is that possible?Here is my code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"  runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" CommandName="odzemi" CssClass="button2" OnClick="btnTest_Click" Text="-" Width="100px" Font-Bold="True" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button15" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Button" />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView>


   protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Counter1"] = newValue;
        Session["Counter"] = newValue;
        if (Session["Markici"] != null || Session["Markici"] != null)
        {

            var clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;

            /*decimal*/ old = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("Kolicina");

            decimal oldIznos = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkIznos");
            decimal VkDanok = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkDanok");
            string Cena1 = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<string>("Cena1");
            int TarifaID = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<Int16>("TarifaID");

           // decimal pocentDanok0 = 0.0m;
          //  decimal pocentDanok1 = 0.18m;              
          //  decimal pocentDanok2 = 0.5m;



            //int oldValue = int.Parse(old); 
           /* decimal*/ newValue = old - 1; //
           Label37.Text = newValue.ToString();

            decimal newIznos = oldIznos - Convert.ToDecimal(Cena1);

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("Kolicina", newValue.ToString());      
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("VkIznos", newIznos.ToString());
```

}
//I want here to call btn_test click and modyfy his values

```
  protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (GridView2.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("MasiGradskaKafanak1.aspx");
        }
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["string2"].ConnectionString);




       Session["Counter"] = counter;
        Label11.Text =  counter.ToString();

      //  Label11.Text = Session["kolicina2"].ToString(); //ViewState["count"].ToString(); //

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Label35.Text = (string)reader["pkid"].ToString();
            Label12.Text = (string)reader["Artikal"].ToString();
            Label33.Text = (string)reader["Vid"].ToString();
            Label34.Text = (string)reader["EdMera"].ToString();
            Label14.Text = (string)reader["TarifaID"].ToString();
            Label13.Text = (string)reader["Cena1"].ToString();




            //iznos
            decimal mnoz = Convert.ToDecimal(Label11.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(Label13.Text);
            Label17.Text = mnoz.ToString();
            decimal.Parse(Label17.Text);

            decimal cena;
            cena = Convert.ToDecimal(Label13.Text);
            decimal kolicina;
            kolicina = Convert.ToDecimal(Label11.Text);
            decimal iznos;
            iznos = Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text);

            Session["cena1"] = Label13.Text;
            Session["iznos1"] = Label17.Text;


            if (Label14.Text == "0")
            {
                decimal pocentDanok = 0.0m;
                vkdanok1 = Convert.ToDecimal(vkdanok1) + Convert.ToDecimal(cena) * Convert.ToDecimal(kolicina) * Convert.ToDecimal(pocentDanok) / (1 + Convert.ToDecimal(pocentDanok));
                vkdanok1 = Math.Truncate(vkdanok1 * 10000m) / 10000m;
                Label18.Text = vkdanok.ToString();//vkdanok
            }
            else if (Label14.Text == "1")
            {

                decimal pocentDanok = 0.18m;
                vkdanok1 = (vkdanok1) + Convert.ToDecimal(cena) * Convert.ToDecimal(kolicina) * Convert.ToDecimal(pocentDanok) / (1 + Convert.ToDecimal(pocentDanok));
                vkdanok1 = Math.Truncate(vkdanok1 * 10000m) / 10000m;
                Label18.Text = vkdanok1.ToString();//VkDanok

            }
            else if (Label14.Text == "2")
            {

                decimal pocentDanok = 0.5m;
                vkdanok1 = Convert.ToDecimal(vkdanok1) + Convert.ToDecimal(cena) * Convert.ToDecimal(kolicina) * Convert.ToDecimal(pocentDanok) / (1 + Convert.ToDecimal(pocentDanok));
                vkdanok1 = Math.Truncate(vkdanok1 * 10000m) / 10000m;
                Label18.Text = vkdanok1.ToString();//vkdanok
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];


        if (Label37.Text == "0")
        {
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Label11.Text;
        }

        else if (Label37.Text != "0")
        {

            Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + Counter1;// Label37.Text;//Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + 3;


        }

        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Artikal"] = Label12.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Cena1"] = Label13.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkIznos"] = Label17.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkDanok"] = Label18.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["EdMera"] = Label34.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["ArtikalID"] = Label35.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Vid"] = Label33.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["TarifaID"] = Label14.Text;

        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
        GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        RemoveDuplicates(dt);
    }
```

Comment: Any idea, example...???

Comment: It is not clear what you trying to achieve, if you want to run functionality of button7 then extract it to private method and run it on both buttons.

Comment: if you want to call button click from another button click event then you can call `btnTest_Click(new object,e)` but if you want to execute the same functionality then as @Zaki mentioned create separate method for the repeating code and call that method.

Comment: protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   if(btnTest_Click(sender,e))
            

            How to check this here in this condition if()?

Comment: how to set this event btn_Test click in if condition?-To check if is clicked in if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EditItemTemplate to corresponding every templatefield in gridview.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee_ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>